# Will my app update automatically or will user need to update the app when the code is updated?

Tags: ios, updates

I am creating a weather app and want to give local warnings to people through an app. I want to be able to give up to date warnings, but I am wondering: does updating information in Xcode get automatically pushed to the devices or will it need an update every time I put new information in?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm unsure what you're asking. What "information" are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly - you have an app, which warns people about some unexpected weather conditions?

You basically have two options:

1. Do a code push to your app every time you do a change. This is not supported by default in Swift and Xcode, and can only be done via some third-party integration or framework (e.g. React Native), and is generally a hard thing to implement.
2. Setup a back-end server and link it with your app, so the new information is downloaded from this back-end server dynamically.

The only suitable and easy thing to do for your use case seems to be option 2.